# Worklight server hangs for local desktop development

Tags: java, javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am working with worklight on Eclipse on a windows machine.  I can never get it to stop or restart properly.  Normally I have to spend 5 minutes trying to delete the server and add back the worklight projects and then it may startup again.  Has anyone experienced this and what is a fix?

When I start Worklight server (local machine), the server just hangs, the bottom right message displays "Starting Worklight Developer Server".

I am using:
Launching worklight (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.0/wlp-1.0.3.20130524-0951) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.6.0_30-b12 (en_US), Worklight Studio / 6.1.0.01 - 2014

Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627

Code Base: nothing really, just a simple HelloWorld Adapter and javascript client code.

There are no error messages, this is the last message in the console.
CWWKZ0001I: Application _MobileBrowserSimulator started in 0.498 seconds.

When visiting the server in the browser, there is no response because it looks like the server is still trying to start.

I usually wait 5 minutes before killing the server in the task manager.  Even after killing the server in the task manager and then closing Eclipse and trying to start the server again...the server still hangs.  Normally, I end up deleting the server and creating another one.

Note: I see a potential issue with the mobile simulator application, but when I remove the mobile simulator, worklight seems to inject it back into the server.

Edit-1: Nothing has really worked.  I am now using Kepler SR1 and new workspace.  It is possible that the server hanging issue has died down but it still happens.  Basically, the only way to kickstart the worklight server is to change the server.xml, delete all the wars/applications (all 2 of them) and then kill the server in the task manager, possibly restarting eclipse and then starting the server again.  There are no errors in the message log.

Comment: instead of killing server did you try creating new workspace and restart the eclipse?

Comment: I did create a new workspace, same issues.  Initially the server may work properly.  But over time, I get the hanging issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what might be wrong with just that information. Can you provide your messages.log file when the server has failed? (It should be under workspace_path/WorklightServerConfig/servers/worklight/logs)

The best way to get the real one we want, would be to use a fresh Eclipse workspace and then reproduce the problem.

Just blinded eyes, as a potential solution, I would try to set a valid IP to the Worklight Development Server, instead using "localhost" which is the default. Have you tried that? In Servers View, double click Worklight Development Server -> Host Name -> SET TO YOUR CURRENT IP. Then do a Run As -> Run on Worklight Development Server again for your application.

Comment: By the way, if you delete and re-add a Liberty server instance, there is a high chance it will not work properly. Worklight provides a customized instance of server.xml that you won't have if you delete the pre-defined one and add a new Liberty instance by hand.

Comment: Otherwise, if you are getting this in the pre-defined server, then you  probably may need to look at this technote: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21668175

Comment: There are no real errors in the message logs, ffdc, etc.  I will try updating to localhost, I don't think that is an issue though.  I increased the timeout to several minutes but it hangs for an infinite amount of time,just deadlocks so the timeout won't really help.  I tried Eclipse SR1 as suggested below, but still the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Kepler SR2 isn't supported for Worklight 6.1x. I don't know if this is the cause, but there was some unpredictable behavior with SR2. I would suggest trying it on Kepler SR1 and see if you get the same behavior. Get links to supported eclipse releases and editions here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/download/

Comment: I tried your suggestion, that helped a little, I believe but the problem persists.  I am run, RAD and don't have any problems. And other version of Eclipse, I haven't had issues.  It is just Eclipse SR1 and the worklight, liberty server that are at issue.    I wonder if there is some cached version of the webapps that are causing a problem, I wonder if I clean those up every so often.